# How to run batch while installing and uninstalling with Inno Setup

Tags: windows, batch-file, inno-setup

I want to install services with batch files:

```
testapp\apache\apache_installservice.bat
testapp\mysql\mysql_installservice.bat
testapp\apache\apache_uninstallservice.bat
testapp\mysql\mysql_uninstallservice.bat
```

I have tried the batch files and they are working properly.

What I need to know is, how to run the install batch files, while installing an application with Inno Setup?
And how to run the uninstall batch files, while uninstalling the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [`[Run]` and `[UninstallRun]` sections](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection):

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\apache\apache_installservice.bat"; \
    StatusMsg: "Installing Apache service"
Filename: "{app}\mysql\mysql_installservice.bat"; \
    StatusMsg: "Installing MySQL service"

[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{app}\apache\apache_uninstallservice.bat"
Filename: "{app}\mysql\mysql_uninstallservice.bat"
```

---

See also [HOWTO: Run batch files](https://web.archive.org/web/20200612000112/https://jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?runbatchfile) in Inno Setup Knowledge Base.